# Part of file in a ftp path can be downloaded but the others get error 550 using filezilla server and client

Tags: ftp, filezilla, ftps, ftp-server

I tried to set a FileZilla FTP Server for my boss. When downloading files from FTP, we got error `550`. I promise I had set all accession for that group, which means they should be able to do anything they want on that path.

Fine, I set accession for each user. It did work, for I can download the test file on the server computer.

Then I came back to my computer and tried to download files from that path, but the only file I did not get error `550` is the test file that I tested on the server computer.

What's going on and what can I do?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've found the answer.

The reason for all that I described is that windows file permissions do not match the FileZilla permission control system. That's where the error 550 comes from.

To limit the **file permissions** of FileZilla, I built a **Guest** user and transferred its ownership to the guest user. This can stop hackers from hacking the system by FileZilla service. When we drag a file to the FTP shared file folder by windows explorer, the file's owner is not the FileZilla administrator, but yourself.

That means FileZilla has no permission to do anything on those files.

The group's working (sorry for I didn't test it). That's why I can see two public folders after I added that shared folder for every user.

The solution is **just use your FileZilla client to transfer files. Do not drag files by explorer.**

Comment: And that's why only part of those files can be downloaded. Those files were uploaded by me from the client, the others were uploaded by my boss from the explorer.